# Wordpress Site Health showing php is out of date... but it is not

Tags: wordpress

I logged into my wordpress site and went to Tools -> Site Health. It says that I am running on a server using PHP 5.6.40 and that some of my setting are not enabled (Imagick, etc.).

The problem is when I go to php.info it shows PHP 7.2. When I check on the server it also says 7.2.

Does anyone know how is this Site Health pulling php info and is there a way to reset it?

Comment: That's odd. Could you please share the contents of your `.htaccess` file? (Edit your question to include it.)

Comment: ^ I agree with the above comment. Also check that your wordpress installation is up to date. Before updating or making changes backup your files and DB. If you're not sure how to check the wp version, check out second step mentioned here: https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000449117-How-do-I-update-PHP-for-my-WordPress-site-#step-2

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having the same problem. I'm running Wordpress 5.3.2